# C# ASP.NET ErrorProcedure or function '(procedure)' expects parameter '(parameter)', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Really need help with this error have been stuck on it for a while.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Procedure or function
>   'spGetVehicleDetailsByID' expects parameter '@vehicle_id', which was
>   not supplied.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            string vehicleId = Request.QueryString["vehicle_id"];

            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetVehicleDetailsByID", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@vehicle_id", vehicleId);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) // The Error is here
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        lblVehicleID.Text = rdr["vehicle_identity"].ToString();
                        lblCategoryID.Text = rdr["category_id"].ToString();
                        lblStartingPrice.Text = rdr["starting_price"].ToString();
                        lblBuyoutPrice.Text = rdr["buyout_price"].ToString();
                        lblMake.Text = rdr["Make"].ToString();
                        lblModel.Text = rdr["Model"].ToString();
                        lblYear.Text = rdr["year"].ToString();
                        lblEngine.Text = rdr["engine"].ToString();
                        lblFuelType.Text = rdr["fuel_type"].ToString();
                        lblFuelSystem.Text = rdr["fuel_system"].ToString();
                        lblCylinders.Text = rdr["cylinders"].ToString();
                        lblDisplacement.Text = rdr["displacement"].ToString();
                        lblTopSpeed.Text = rdr["top_speed"].ToString();
                        lblAcceleration.Text = rdr["acceleration"].ToString();
                        lblFuelConsumption.Text = rdr["fuel_consumption"].ToString();
                        lblDriveType.Text = rdr["drive_type"].ToString();
                        lblTransmission.Text = rdr["transmission"].ToString();
                        lblBrakesFront.Text = rdr["brakes_front"].ToString();
                        lblBrakesBack.Text = rdr["brakes_back"].ToString();
                        lblLength.Text = rdr["length"].ToString();
                        lblWidth.Text = rdr["width"].ToString();
                        lblHeight.Text = rdr["height"].ToString();
                        lblWheelbase.Text = rdr["wheelbase"].ToString();
                        lblGroundClearance.Text = rdr["ground_clearance"].ToString();
                        lblCargoVolume.Text = rdr["cargo_volume"].ToString();
                        lblUnladenWeight.Text = rdr["unladen_weight"].ToString();
                        lblGrossWeight.Text = rdr["gross_weight"].ToString();
                    }
```

Here is the [Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntBuP.png) it wouldn't let me past the SQL query in for some reason. Here is what is being returned to [vehicleId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqRsk.png)

Comment: Add the code in your post to make it easier for others to read and understand your question. You will have a better chance of getting help if your post is easy to read and understand

Comment: I noticed the type of variable in your stored procedure is INT but in your C# code is string. Is it possible that you have a non-numeric character in your string type value? (could be a white space character) . Can you convert the value into integer in your C# code before assigning the value to the command's parameter?

Comment: @Sparrow Sorry first time using this site ill add the code now. Its just returning the ID of vehicles which is a single digit number at the moment as i only have a couple stored in the DB

Comment: @NathanPicton your code is correct. The error you mentioned will come only when `vehicleId` is NULL. Can you debug and see what is the value set to `vehicleId` from `Request.QueryString["vehicle_id"]`. If `Request.QueryString` does not have key `vehicle_id` the variable `vehicleid` will be NULL. And that will cause this error to occur.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yeah it is returning as NULL i'm not really sure what to do from here I've added a screen shot of what it returns at the bottom next to the procedure. It should be returning the ID number

Comment: What is your requirement? The solution depends on that. If vehicleid is NULL what should be returned by the procedure? Or you don't want to call the stored procedure if `vehicelid` is NULL ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It should be returning the ID of the vehicle that has been selected from the last page so that all of the details from that vehicle are displayed on this page.

Comment: Then you need to check why the querystring parameter is not being populated from the last page.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks that helped me find it, it turned out that i was missing a "=" sign on the previous page in the query string... So frustrating haha.